# References to Bisrakh in the scriptures

Tags: ramayana, history, ravana, geography

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisrakh) wiki article says that *Bisrakh* in Uttar Pradesh is believed to be the birthplace of *Ravana*. Are any scriptural references available for this?

Comment: Interesting question. I have also heard from some friends from UP that Mandodari was born in Meerut. Not sure if there are any references though but will answer if I find.